# resize image in iPhone 5

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I need resize image and for this I use some code:

```
myImage = [myImage resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(
btnImg.size.height / 3,
btnImg.size.width / 3,
btnImg.size.width / 3 * 2,
btnImg.size.height / 3 * 2)]; 
WPRImageView *btnImgView = [[WPRImageView alloc] initWithImage:btnImg];
```

" / 3 " i need to no harm to corners of image

In all devices it work good, but only in iPhone 5 (not iPhone 5s)
I have some problem (in image)

Thanks..

[image: expected result]
[image: i have in iPhone 5]

Comment: Did you add your image with different resolutions ˋ@1x` ˋ@2x` and ˋ@3x` ?

Comment: Yes, of course. and in iPhone 5 this is @1x

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can be related to incorrect use of `UIEdgeInsetsMake` this method need the parameters on this order

```
UIEdgeInsetsMake(top,left,bottom,right)
```

and you are passing

```
UIEdgeInsetsMake(btnImg.size.height / 3,btnImg.size.width / 3,btnImg.size.width / 3 * 2,btnImg.size.height / 3 * 2)
```

so try this

```
UIEdgeInsetsMake(btnImg.size.height / 3,btnImg.size.width / 3,btnImg.size.height / 3 * 2, btnImg.size.width / 3 * 2)
```

I hope this helps you